# Instruct WebApp using Django to run the code locally and return results

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am a newbie to web development and python scripts. I am learning to host python scripts using Django. I would like to know how to instruct Django to run the script locally instead of running it on the server.

For e.g. User visits the web app > enters parameters and submits the form > script should run locally from the client machine and return results back on the web app.

The purpose of my python script is to test the network port status locally on the user machine's private network and return the results.

Appreciate your advise.

Comment: You can use a command when you run the manage.py https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: You can't run a python script from your server on the clients machine... There are several points to be considered not to mention allowing such things to be possible would be a big security concern. If you want to do anything client side use JavaScript

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks All for the suggestion., Let me explore more on JavaScript and also take more Django lessons before deciding any further.